# Perl-regex word-boundary equivalence

Tags: regex, perl

Extending my basic regex knowledge, and some things are unclear for me.

If the `\b` matches word boundary has the next two regexes the same meaning - e.g. will match the same strings?

```
/\bword\b/
/(^|\W)word(\W|$)/m    #when multi-line is turned on
/(\A|\W)word(\W|\z)/
```

asking because the `\b` means *word boundary*. The word is `\w+`, so the `\b` must be anything what isn't `\w`, e.g. it must be `\W` or the begining or the end of string, or line. (or no?) (not counting capture groups, probably would be better to use some non-capturing look-somewhere).

and those two?

```
/word\B/
/word\w/
```

If the *word* must be "nonword-boundary" at the end, that means thet the *word* must be followed by `\w` (word) character. (or no?)

Comment: Btw, `/(^|\W)word(\W|$)/`, `/(^|\W)word(\W|$)/m`, `/(\A|\W)word(\W|\z)/` and `/(\A|\W)word(\W|\z)/m` all match the same thing.

Comment: @ikegami hm... Again I understand something wrong. ;( To this time i think than the `/some$/` wouldn't match the `some\nstring` but the `/some$/m` would. and the `/some\z/` will never match the `"some\nstring"` regardless of the `m`. What I missed? Should I ask a new question?

Comment: @ikegami YES, now got it (I hope)! when the `m` is missing, the newline is matched by the `\W`.

Comment: Right, newline isn't a word character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Ignore whitespace in the following patterns. I assumed `/x` is being used for readability.)

---

```
\b
```

is equivalent to

```
(?<!\w)(?=\w) | (?<=\w)(?!\w)
```

so

```
\b word \b
```

is equivalent to

```
(?: (?<!\w)(?=\w) | (?<=\w)(?!\w) ) word (?: (?<!\w)(?=\w) | (?<=\w)(?!\w) )
```

which simplifies to

```
(?<!\w) word (?!\w)
```

What you suggested as equivalents are slightly different.

---

```
\B
```

is equivalent to

```
(?<=\w)(?=\w) | (?<!\w)(?!\w)
```

so

```
word \B
```

is equivalent to

```
word (?: (?<=\w)(?=\w) | (?<!\w)(?!\w) )
```

which simplifies to

```
word (?=\w)
```

What you suggested as equivalent (`word\w`) is slightly different.

Comment: Only wondering how anyone can remember (and use) all those positive/negative look behind/ahead constructions... ;( Great answer, thank you. (and probably my next qst will be about the equivqlence of the `/(?!)/` (FAIL) and `/(?<!)/` (FAIL TOO) ... :))

Comment: `(?=...)` means followed by. `(?!...)` means not followed by. `(?<=...)` means preceded by. `(?<!...)` means not preceded by. `=` and `!` are easy to remember, and `<` means before instead of after.

Answer (score 3):

`\bword` is the same as `(?<!\w)word` and `word\b` is the same as `word(?!\w)`

`\Bword` is equal to `(?<=\w)word` and `word\B` equal `word(?=\w)`